# Wrong metakey in dialog boxes in PhpStorm and IntelliJ (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, phpstorm

ellou'

In all dialog boxes of PhpStorm (3.0) and IntelliJ (11.0) keyboard shortcuts are connected with ALT key instead of CMD. In such case when I'm trying to write ie. commit message in VCS dialog in with Polish characters some of them just switches some checkboxes or focuses some fields :) (ie. in "Commit Changes" dialog ALT + o switches checbox "Optimize imports" instead inserting "ó" character.

Is there any possibility to change shortucts key to CMD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82390) that will be addressed in the next PhpStorm release. It is already [fixed for the IntelliJ IDEA platform](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/intellij-idea-111-rc4/), there will be an option in `Preferences` | `Appearance`: **Disable mnemonics in controls**.

Comment: IntelliJ 11.1 - it's alive ! :) Disabling mnemonics in controls works for me pretty well! Thanx